# SQL output Streamline

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a batch file that runs an `SQL` script to run weekly, fortnightly, monthly or yearly reports.

The script I use is:

```
SELECT name, Output, TrendTime FROM LoopDef
Where TrendTime between ‘01-Jul-19 00:00:01’ and ‘01-Jul-19 01:00:00’
OR LIKE ‘%%-%%-%% %%:15:%%’
OR LIKE ‘%%-%%-%% %%:30:%%’
OR LIKE ‘%%-%%-%% %%:45:%%’
OR LIKE ‘%%-%%-%% %%:00:%%’
Order by name, Output, TrendTime’;
```

This outputs every 00, 15, 30 & 45 min, sadly I get multiples for 0-60 seconds.

Is there a straightforward way of omitting the extra results and just have one outputted value per `LIKE`?

Answer (score 0):

If the duplicates is the only issue, you can just add DISTINCT after the SELECT command:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, ...
```

Comment: As my wildcards only require 00, 15, 30 & 45......Distinct may just work. Couldn’t see the wood for the trees. I will test and let you know Peter - thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, Output, TrendTime FROM LoopDef
WHERE (TrendTime BETWEEN '30-JUN-19 00:00:01' AND '01-JUL-19 01:00:00')
GROUP BY name, Output, TrendTime
HAVING TrendTime LIKE '%%-%%%-%% %%:00:%%'
OR TrendTime LIKE '%%-%%%-%% %%:15:%%'
OR TrendTime LIKE '%%-%%%-%% %%:30:%%'
OR TrendTime LIKE '%%-%%%-%% %%:45:%%'
ORDER BY name, TrendTime;
```

Sadly still getting multiple Outputs. eg:

```
"Main_Loop                     19.9 30-JUN-19 00:30:00"
"Main_Loop                     19.8 30-JUN-19 00:30:04"
"Main_Loop                     19.8 30-JUN-19 00:30:56"
```

Comment: what do mean by still getting multiple Outputs? as I see all three records has different seconds and the 1st and second record has an output parameter different

Comment: Ideally it would be good to see 00, 15, 30 & 45 for a time period. 30:00, 30:04 & 30:36.....ideally just one.
Some results are 5-10 records long and only seconds are the difference.